# Sending a final PDF back to originator

Tags: javascript, adobe

Is there a code I could use to send a PDF based on an email entered previous text field once it has been signed? Meaning, if John Smith or Jane Doe the originator and I approve or deny his request and digitally sign it, how can I get it back to either one of them based on the email they entered in a field. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: They enter their email in an input?

Comment: @Alex - Their email is in on of the text boxes on the form. I need to be able to extract that email as soon as the boss clicks on a button to return that document to the requestor.